# I want to update order status using magento's rest api

Tags: module, javascript, rest-api, php-7, magento2.3.5-p1

I want to use Magento Api for Updating Status of order in Magento 2.3.5 so anyone can guide me from scratch how can i use api. I also want to know in Magento how many default api is there and how to use api in php file. so anyone have idea then please share with me.

Thank you In Advace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this api {{your url}}rest/V1/orders and apply following params to update status

```
{
    "entity": {
        "entity_id": orderid,
        "state":"processing",
        "status": "processing"
    }
}
```

Comment: hello  how can i call rest api in php file inmagento 2

Comment: because i don't know how to write api code in magento 2

Comment: please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Please follow link create module and still you face any problem let me know

https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-custom-rest-api-in-magento-2/

Comment: This answer will become useless if the site goes down.